# Create certificate with Windows 7 for WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-7, certificate

I need to get a simple certificate(root and cert) for a .NET WCF TCP Selfhost application. I know that this cert will only be for test.

Here is a site that shows how to create a self-signed cert : http://www.deepakkapoor.net/generate-self-signed-certificates-on-windows-7/ but this will only get me one file? Don't I need 2 files(root and cert)?

Also it's important that this cert will work in another domain(not knowing of the computer that issues the cert).

All I need is a cert to encrypt data between Service and Client based on WCF/TCP/Selfhost/Winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using point 8 in this article : http://robbincremers.me/2011/12/29/wcf-message-security-and-client-certificate-authentication-with-self-signed-certificates/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried but I would thing Windows non-server edition does not have in built/easy to find functionality for setting up your own root.

I would use OpenSSL to generate the root and the generate the certificate and sign it with the  root.

Here is a guide that tells you how to do just that.

http://thephuck.com/virtualization/creating-your-own-root-ca-with-openssl-on-windows-and-signing-vcenter-or-srm-certs/